# Multi threaded server sending and receiving data between two clients at same time

Tags: java, sockets

What I need is a server that can receive data from any client and send it to any other clients that are connected. I've looked all over the internet for help but everything I try fails.

I need the server to run on a single port. I need it to be able to send strings in this format: `ID:XPOS:ZPOS:ROTATION:ECT` e.g. `256:56:88:90:Steve`. Then I need the other clients to receive this and split it.

The server will need to be threaded so that it can support multiple clients.

Comment: Being able to support multiple client doesn't necessarily mean a multi-threaded server - java.nio allows for IO multiplexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this with `BlockingQueue`s. It's not the best solution though, `java.nio` scales much more better but i guess it works for something around 50 clients perfectly.

You can create a thread for each client, in that thread you have an infinite loop which waits for a queue to get items from. When the queue is empty all client threads are blocked so there is no busy waits. Whenever a message needs to be broadcasted add it to the message queue of clients.

```
class Server {
    public static final int port = 11111;
    private final ServerSocket mServerSocket;
    private final Collection<Client> mClients;
    private boolean acceptNewClients;

    public Server() {
        mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        mClients = new ArrayList<Client>();
        acceptNewClients = true;

        ThreadManager.t.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Client c;
                while (acceptNewClients) {
                    // On new client connected
                    c = new Client(mServerSocket.accept());
                    mClients.add(c);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void broadcast(String message) {
        for (Client c : mClients) 
            c.sendMessage(message);
    }
}

class ThreadManager {
    public static final ExecutorService t = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();   
}

final class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket mSocket;
    private OutputStreamWriter mWriter;
    private InputStreamReader mReader;
    private boolean mContinueNetworking;
    private LinkedBlockingDeque<String> mCommandsToSend;

    public Client(Socket s) {
        mSocket = s;
        mWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        mReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        mCommandsToSend = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>();

        mContinueNetworking = true;
        ThreadManager.t.execute(this);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        mCommandsToSend.addLast(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String message;
        while (mContinueNetworking) {
            message = mCommandsToSend.take();
            try {
                mWriter.write(message);
                mWriter.write('\n');
                mWriter.flush();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mContinueNetworking = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // optional: uncomment for retry in case of failure
//                 commandsToSend.put(toSend);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never used java nio. Anyway thanks if you could show me and example that'd be great.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go now. If I run into any problems would I be able to contact you?

Comment: @Guitcube use comments section here

Comment: It was useful. It gave me clues to how sockets work. Anyway I've decided to use a lib.